# Why Are "Opportunities" showing up twice under related lists?

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, page-layout, lightning-components

On my Account and Contact page layouts I am seeing two "Opportunities" under related lists...

Opportunity object only has a lookup to AccountId and my Account object has no lookup to Opportunity. What is this second related list?

[image]

Comment: Odds are, it's a custom lookup field on Opportunity. You probably just missed it.

Comment: thank you, I missed it, marking this one as correct

Comment: I tend to name the custom relationship something like `XXX Opportunities` or `Opportunities (as XXX)` to avoid this issue

Answer (score 2):

Opportunity object has one default field lookup to account(AccountId) with relationship name (Opportunities). Please check is there another lookup field made on opportunity with account with same relationship name(Opportunities) therefore two opportunities are shown.